# How to achieve backwards compatibility during Java app update?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I ran at the problem of keeping backwards compatibility during app update. I have a client-server architecture and client sends to a server some information and in response receives up-to-date data. In the next version of the app, some new fields and methods are added. And if I use old client version some errors (like null pointers or incorrect workflow) may appear on server. I can check new features for null, but when there're 3-4 different version clients - we'll have spaghetti-code and a lot of potential hidden bugs.

Are there any design patterns that will help to resolve this problem? How to react on different client version?

Thank you, in advance.

Comment: What kind of client-server communication technology do you use?

Comment: What kind of apps are you talking about? Java Applets?

Comment: Generally I use GWT for client but there's standalone app that communicates with server and displays data in GWT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this approach: Add a version field either to the login message each client message.

The latter works if you don't have a session. If the version field is missing, you know it's "version 0".

On the server dispatch messages to handlers based on the version field. Many handlers can be split into an abstract base class which handles the common cases plus simple extensions per message version.

This allows you to avoid the spaghetti code.

Comment: +1 A more extreme version of this is to have a different port for different versions. Each port has its own code with the old port having the old code and protocol, the new port having the new protocol. You can see how many clients are connecting to old ports and from where and remove them when they are no longer needed.

Answer (score 2):

I wold take a look at the [Adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern). This can be used to make different class work together.

Answer (score 1):

Some tips:

- **Add a version number** to new versions of the message. This will help a lot!
- **Create validation routines** for each message version. This serves multiple purposes: you can validate that the message is actually correct given it's stated version number, you can work out the vesrion of a message that doesn't have a version number, and you can validate input at runtime, and it will help you with testing. Validating against an XML schema can be useful for this.
- **Handle the message version as early as possible** - i.e. as soon as your code sees the message after it is received. The earlier you tackle version issues, the less of your code base needs to handle multiple versions.
- **If possible, convert old version messages to the new version messages** - this is usually quite simple to do (maybe adding a couple of fields with default values), and means that the rest of your code base can assume the new version message (and you've got validation routines to prove it, right??)
- **As a last resort only: write custom handlers for different message versions** - this might be necessary if there was a significant change in business logic between different client versions.